# How to run two display from different projects in single window in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

there are two qml projects. I want to create another project which includes these two projects and only one window which contains others' windows. Should I use subdirs or another and how ?

Comment: Please provide a minimal and complete example. It will be hard to give you the right answer without it

Comment: For example, i have a project whose output is video player and another project whose output is simple image. I want to create a main project and its has a window as output. one half of this window should get video player and other half is image. How should structure be ? Basicly, one screen should be two rectangele half and half and these are other subprojects.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using qmake, you should probably take a look into this [link](https://wiki.qt.io/SUBDIRS_-_handling_dependencies). The idea is to keep each subproject as an independent project.

Each of those projects should provide the different components you may use, I guess GUI components. You can create a main one that depends on both of them.

```
/MyAwesomeApp
   |--- subdirs.pro
   `--- src
        |
        |--- app
        |    |--- app.pro
        |    `--- ... (source files of app)
        |--- guilibA
        |    |--- guilibA.pro
        |    `--- ... (source files of lib)
        `--- guilibB
             |--- guilibB.pro
             `--- ... (source files of lib2)
```

Comment: I could not use guilibA and guilibB in my app. How can I use? In addition, could you give some details about main.qml file of app? Also, is there any change different from above in pro file? Thanks.